# Reading a XML File from a servlet class and displaying it on JSP page

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

First of all i would like to know whether my approach is correct or not.
I have products that are stored in a xml file. I will be reading this file, and storing Products, so that i can pass it to the JSP page. Here is my Product.xml file

I would also like to know, what sort of data structure I should use. Since on the products page, I will have an ADD TO CART button, for every product.

```
<inventory>
<product>
    <name>Dictionairy</name>
    <description>Words from the English language</description>
    <price>400</price>

</product>
<product>
    <name>Calculator</name>
    <description>solving numbers</description>
    <price>1000</price>

</product>
<product>
    <name>LCD</name>
    <description>displaying output from computer</description>
    <price>8000</price>
</product>
</inventory>
```

Comment: To start, using a XML file as database is already bad. It's inefficient and memory hogging. Is there any particular reason why you can't use a SQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as a quick shot I'd go for a class `Inventory` containing a collection of `Product` classes which represent all possible products. Then have a class `Cart` which can also contain products (references to the products) as well as a quantity (this might actually be a `CartPosition` and `Cart` holds positions).

Note that `Inventory` should be stored in application scope, since it seems to be the same for each customer. Keep in mind that access to the inventory might need to be synchronized or it should at least be locked/hidden until fully read. `Cart` on the other hand might be stored in the session.

Also note that this is a very simple approach. Doing a real shop involves a lot more.

Comment: Yes you're right, i have a class Product, CartItem that holds the product , and a shoppingCart class that contians the methods for adding/removing items from the cart. I dont have an inventory class. is that required for a shoppingcart? Will i need this class to populate all products in the xml file ? 

secondly, how should i go about reading the products from the xml file, and displaying htem on the products jsp page. Should i use invetory class to populate products or use x:out and iterate through each item, or use another approach.

Comment: The Inventory itself is not obligatory but I'd recommend it as a central storage for the available products. It could provide methods to look up products, hold stock per product etc. As for reading the XML: I'd not do that per request or session, since as Stephen pointed out, this is quite heavy weight. You should read the XML at startup or when it changes and store the resulting objects in application scope (that's what the Inventory class is for).

Answer (score 3):

Parsing the XML in the servlet and turning it into an in-memory data structure that the JSP can use sounds rather heavy-weight.

Passing XML to a JSP which then parses and traverses it sounds even worse.

If the servlet is extracting kosher XML, and the task of the rendering code is simply to filter and render the content as HTML, then maybe you should be looking at an XSLT processor rather than a JSP to do the rendering.

Indeed, you could even send the XML in the HTML response with an embedded processing directive to tell the client-side what XSL to use ... if it wants to.